# Is there a way to execute jq from python

Tags: python, arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to execute a jq command from my python script. Currently the jq command is working fine when I execute from the terminal (MacOs).

```
cat filename.json |jq '{Name:.name, address:.address[0][1].street}'
```

Basically I'm trying to extract data from a JSON using jq. As the JSON contains nested arrays, I would have to loop using a variable.

My questions is -

- Can I execute this command from a python script
- If it can be done, then how would I loop through for the nested array
- elements in the sample data give above (address[][].street)

I don't want to use any language other than python, as it would cause compatibility issues.

Comment: 1- you can start `jq` like any other external program (`subprocess` module) 2- to extract data from JSON, use `json` module in Python (no need to run any shell command). Provide example JSON input and the desired output and what you get instead.

Comment: "As the JSON contains nested arrays, I would have to loop using a variable." what does this mean? jq can perform operations on nested arrays just fine. Can you provide a sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 20):

From the jq [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ):

> Q: What bindings are available for Python?
>
> A:
>
> pip install jq # For details, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq
>
> pip install pyjq # For details, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjq

As for your nested array, looping through it sounds like something that can (and maybe should) be done within jq.

Comment: Unable to install both of them, can you help me in installing this.

Comment: I used jq library with Python3 and parsed the JSON data. What is the problem with installation?

Comment: Not sure this is compatible on Windows environment: https://pypi.org/project/jq/

Comment: I don't clearly understand the difference between `jq` and `pyjq` can anyone please help?

Comment: I compared `jq` and `pyjq`, and the immediately differences I see are that 1) they use different APIs, and 2) they have slightly different dependencies and build requirements. But besides that they appear to be fairly similar.

Comment: Note that pyjq doesn't work on Windows, it needs Linux tools to build it

Comment: As of February 2022, pyjq is still broken.  It throws fatal errors when trying to install it.  No patches in site.

Answer (score 11):

I believe the accepted answer should be peak's one, as the proper way to use a C api in python is via a python binding lib, and both https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjq should work as expected.

---

That being said, since we are talking about python, I would like to bring an alternative that is much more pythonic: **glom** (`pip install glom`, https://glom.readthedocs.io/)

Instead of using a DSL like in `jq`, with `glom` you just declare the output in the format you want, using pure python (this output format is called `spec`). In this case, you want a simple `dict`:

```
spec = {'Name': 'name',
        'street': 'address.0.1.street'}
```

and then just call glom on your data:

```
output_data = glom(input_data, spec)
```

Just like `jq`, you can also use `glom` on command line:

```
cat filename.json | glom "{'Name': 'name', 'street': 'address.0.1.street'}"
```

A complete python example:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from glom import glom


with open('filename.json', 'rt') as f:
    input_data = json.load(f)

spec = {'Name': 'name',
        'street': 'address.0.1.street'}

output_data = glom(input_data, spec)

pprint(output_data)
```

Comment: What if I want to use those jq bindings with the options like `-n` or `--stream` or others which I can only pass line jq programme from the command? In that case using `subprocess` is the only way. Or not?

Answer (score 9):

Well, I'm a big fan of jq, but it doesn't seem like you're doing something that can't be easily done in Python too. Consider:

```
import json

with open("filename.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

{"Name": data["name"], "address": data["address"][0][1]["street"]}
```

Comment: This answer is technically not a direct answer to the OP question but for sure if the OP intends to use python as claimed, then dropping jq and using the `json` module is the way to go.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to handle the stream character in JSON filds while working with Python.

Answer (score 5):

The [`sh`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module makes it easy invoke a jq subprocess from python.  e.g.

```
import sh
cmd = sh.jq('-M', '{Name:.name, address:.address[0][1].street}', 'filename.json')
print "cmd returned >>%s<<" % cmd.stdout
```

Comment: Furthermore, to run jq on data in a string:


`print(jq("-M", ".", _in='{ "a": 3 }').stdout.decode())`

(That's Python 3)

Comment: @tobych - that should be `sh.jq(...)`

Answer (score 2):

1. Can I execute this command from a python script

Yes, using subprocess.  Example:

```
jsonFile = '/path/to/your/filename.json'
jq_cmd = "/bin/jq '{Name:.name, address:.address[0][1].street}' " + jsonFile
jq_proc = subprocess.Popen(jq_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# read JSON object, convert to string, store as a dictionary

jDict = json.loads(jq_proc.stdout.read())
jq_proc.stdout.close()
```

2. If it can be done, then how would I loop through for the nested array
   elements in the sample data give above (address[][].street)

It would help to see a JSON data set with a few records.  For looping through JSON sets in python with jq, it is easy to get a count of the objects and then iterate.  A slight bit of overhead but it makes the code easy to understand.

```
# count number of JSON records from the root level

jq_cmd = "/bin/jq '. | length' " + jsonFile
jq_proc = subprocess.Popen(jq_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

jObjCount = int(jq_proc.stdout.read())
jq_proc.stdout.close()

# iterate over each root level JSON record

for ix in range(jObjCount):

  jq_cmd = "jq '. | .[" + str(ix) + "]' " + jsonFile 
  jq_proc = subprocess.Popen(jq_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

  # read object, convert to string, store as a python dictionary

  jDict = json.loads(jq_proc.stdout.read())

  # iterate over nested objects within a root level object    
  # as before, count number items but here for each root level JSON object

  jq_cmd = "/bin/jq '. | .[" + str(ix) + "].sub_Item_Key | length' " + jsonFile
  jq_proc = subprocess.Popen(jq_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  jItemCount = int(jq_proc.stdout.read())
  jq_proc.stdout.close()

  for jx in range(jItemCount):

     jq_cmd = "/bin/jq '. | .[" + str(ix) + "].sub_Item_Key[" + str(jx) + "]' " + jsonFile
     jq_proc = subprocess.Popen(jq_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

     # read JSON item, convert to string, store as a python dictionary

     jItemDict = json.loads(jq_proc.stdout.read())
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```py
from plumbum.cmd import jq, cat

(cat["filename.json"] | jq ["{Name:.name, address:.address[0][1].street}"])()
```

The result of the above command is a JSON object, that can be parsed to a Python object using `json.loads`.

You might also be interested in [jello](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jello), which is like `jq` but uses Python as query language.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a JQ Python binding called [JQpy](https://baterflyrity.github.io/jqpy/).** This one does not require user to compile anything hence simply works on Linux/Windows/e.t.c.

### Installation

Linux:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jq
pip install jqpy
```

[Windows](https://baterflyrity.github.io/jqpy/installation.html#installation):

```bash
choco install jq
pip install jqpy
```

### Example

```py
>>> from jqpy import jq
>>> jq('.results[] | {age, city}', {
                "timestamp": 1234567890,
                "report": "Age Report",
                "results": [
                        { "name": "John", "age": 43, "city": "TownA" },
                        { "name": "Joe",  "age": 10, "city": "TownB" }
                ]
        })
[{'age': 43, 'city': 'TownA'}, {'age': 10, 'city': 'TownB'}]
```

### Original question

```py
import json, jqpy

# 1. Load JSON data
with open('filename.json','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f)

# 2. Process with JQpy
processed = jqpy.jq('{Name:.name, address:.address[0][1].street}', data)[0]

# 3. Do stuff with outcome
print(f'{processed['Name']=}')
```