# JSON schema conversion in python

Tags: python, json

How to do JSON schema conversion in python? 
I know Jolt serves this purpose, but its in Java.
I have 2 JSON objects, one being the input and second being the mapper. I have tried to implement this by walking the 2 json objects and applying the transformation. However, I am not sure if its an efficient way.

Here's an example:

**Input**

```
{
     "name": "Bob Odenkirk",
     "title": "Software Engineer",
     "location": {
         "locality": "San Francisco",
         "region": "CA",
         "country": "United States"
     },
     "age": 62,
     "status": "Active"
}
```

**Output**

```
{
     "names": ["Bob Odenkirk"],
     "occupations": ["Software Engineer"],
     "locations": ["San Francisco, CA"]    
}
```

Comment: @FranzKafka, how about using JSONPath-rw to read source and create a new json out of it

Comment: ping @franz-kafka IIRC you have put a bounty on this question, but now it's closed, hope you could provide some feedback.

Comment: @georgexsh How do I accept the answer and give you the bounty now that the question is closed? I find it ridiculous that this question was closed in the first place to be honest. Anyway, your answer is good, in that it helps me. I was just hoping there was something out there that allowed for a JSON type DSL like Jolt, where you can write the spec in JSON and then use that as the instructions for how input is transformed to output.

Comment: @FranzKafka I have no knowledge of Jolt, but the richness of expression ability of jq is comparable with jolt IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sound like your need is something can be done with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). There are python binds, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220370/is-there-a-way-to-execute-jq-from-python).

But without knowing your input and output format, it cannot be said lightly jq is your very choice.

---

Take the JSON input in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487436/map-one-json-schema-to-a-different-json-schema) as an example using `pyjq`:

```
import json
import pyjq


json_input = json.loads("""{
    "name": "Bob Odenkirk",
    "title": "Software Engineer",
    "location": {
        "locality": "San Francisco",
        "region": "CA",
        "country": "United States"
    },
    "age": 62,
    "status": "Active"
}""")

r = pyjq.one(
    '{names: [.name], occupations: [.title], locations: [.location.locality + ", " + .location.region]}',
    json_input,
)

print(json.dumps(r, indent=4))
```

yields:

```
{
    "names": [
        "Bob Odenkirk"
    ],
    "occupations": [
        "Software Engineer"
    ],
    "locations": [
        "San Francisco, CA"
    ]
}
```