# how can I get json value select from multiple values with python and jq

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7, jq

I have been struggling with json stuff. I have "unit_number" and "key" values and I want to find backing_uuid based on the unit_number and key values. How can I do that with python? I think like this jq query but I've never tried before. I don't know how can I call jq in python.

```
jq .guest_disk_facts[] |  select(any(.attributes[]?; .unit_number=="2" and .key" == "2002")).backing_uuid and output: 9000da43-8471-57a6-8b18-4425a356b3cb
```

I have json file like this:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "guest_disk_facts": {
        "0": {

            "backing_uuid": "9000da43-8471-57a6-8b18-92381ab3c3f6",
            "key": 2000,
            "unit_number": 0
        },
        "1": {
            "backing_uuid": "9000da43-8471-57a6-8b18-2788c2398ba7",
            "key": 2001,
            "unit_number": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "backing_uuid": "9000da43-8471-57a6-8b18-4425a356b3cb",
            "key": 2002,
            "unit_number": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for thing in dic['guest_disk_facts']:
    if thing['key'] == key and thing['unit_number'] == unit_number:
        print(thing['backing_uuid'])
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .unit_number and .key are already numbers, the jq query would be:

```
.guest_disk_facts[]
| select(.unit_number==2 and .key == 2002).backing_uuid
```

As for using python with jq, see e.g. [Is there a way to execute jq from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220370/is-there-a-way-to-execute-jq-from-python)

Comment: Hi peak, Thanks for reply but how can I use jq in python? is this style: "cat file.json | jq query " ?